# extract YouTube URL from random text in PHP

Tags: php, url, youtube, preg-match

Im trying to extract a YouTube link from just random text. e.g.

This is some random text and url is `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d3RYW0YoEk&feature=channel` and I want to pull this URL out of this text in PHP. Can't seem to figure it out. Found a solution in another language but don't know how to convert it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I put the URL in the text on purpose. My whole paragraph/explanation would be the random text with the URL somewhere in the text. I didn't separate the URL because I would want to retrieve the URL out of some text and that was my example.

Comment: Just to clarify, there's no [X]HTML tags surrounding the URLs, they're just lumped & mixed up in plain old (non multibyte) text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to grab all such  URL's as:

```
if(preg_match_all('~(http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=[%&=#\w-]*)~',$input,$m)){
 // matches found in $m
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should make the `www.` part optional.

Comment: This will also match `http://www.youtube.example.com/watch?v=…` or even `http://www.youtube.com is the YouTube’s URL; but http://example.com/watch?v=… isn’t.`.

Comment: This works very well. Thank very much. I've been pulling my hair out. :) 
@kitsched I don't think ti will matter too much because YouTube will direct you to www.youtube.com if you just type in YouTube.com so the chance of the URL not have www when someone copies and paste is small.

Comment: Just to complicate things, there's one more case: when the user copies a URL from a tweet it looks like youtu.be/xxx :)

Comment: @kitsched, Yeah I know. Oh well. I might tackle that another time, unless someone already has a solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use Regex

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match`.

The pattern should be something like:

```
/(http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=\w{11})/
```